# Getting System Error when accessing Amadeus Test API (Flight Inspiration Search)

Tags: amadeus

I've been using the Amadeus test API for about 2 weeks now and the first week I was able to make requests locally with clientId/clientSecret for my app and through the online Swagger page using the refresh token. Recently, I've been getting System errors for requests. As an example, I try executing the default request for the Flight Inspiration API:

GET https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations?origin=MAD

That request turns the following response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 500,
      "code": 141,
      "title": "SYSTEM ERROR HAS OCCURRED",
      "detail": "Return status (28507/23)"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can see an Access token is generated in the Swagger page just fine using my app's credentials. This system error is happening locally for similar requests and in other example requests in Swagger pages for other Amadeus APIs. Initial thoughts are that there was an outage or an issue with the Test API environment but this has been happening for the past few days. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: We are facing an issue with the API in the test environment. I will add an update as soon as it it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has been fixed in the test environment.

Comment: Tested and call to Test API succeeded. Thanks!